# With a python matrix M (using numpy), how can I compare each column of that matrix with all other columns?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, comparison-operators

I want to see whether there is a way to compare a column of a matrix with all other columns of the same matrix, without using loops. Obviously the result can be extremely large and for a [m x n] matrix will grow in size with n**2. But with reasonable values n it is hopefully possible.

Concretely I have a matrix like:

```
|  1  -1  1  1  -1 |
| -1  -1  1  1   1 |
| -1   1 -1 -1   1 |
|  1  -1  1 -1   1 |
```

And need to get AND and XOR values (or other logical comparisons) for all combinations of columns. Is this possible without loops? I am relatively new to Python, R and Octave, but have encountered similar problems already several times. So a solution in Python or other languages would be most welcome!

Example:

```
| 1 -1  1 |     | 2 0 2 0 -2 0 2 0  1 | 
| 1  1 -1 |  => | 2 2 0 2  2 0 0 0 -2 |
|-1  1  1 |     |-2 0 0 0  2 2 0 2  2 |
```

[ column 1 + matrix , column 2 + matrix , column 3 + matrix ]

It's getting big very fast. There is a lot of duplication, for example I do not need to have a column added to itself, and I do not really need to compare each column with all other columns, but better with all the columns with higher column number (on the right side). Perhaps it is easier to implement it like example above. And maybe it is just not possible! I can imagine this is the kind of function that quickly absorbs all available memory!

Comment: What are you comparing exactly, a column with the column in the same position?

Comment: Yes, in the simplest form I want to just add columns. Comparing column 1 with column 2 (let's call them C1 and C2) will thus give me vector [0 -2 0 0] (transposed). So that I can conclude the  pairwise C1 AND C2, C1 OR C2 and C1 XOR C2, etc. Alternatively I can change the values in the matrix to zeros and ones, and directly apply logical operators. But crucially for it to work, is to have a way to compare all pairs of columns. Thanks!

Comment: Currently what I do is to take columns from the matrix and compare these to the submatrix of all columns right of the one I am comparing with (this because after comparing, say, C1 with C3, I do not need to compare C3 with C1.  So the good news is that is easy to add/subtract/compare a vector with a matrix (numpy understands you probably mean to have the vector operate on each column), but I do not see a way to get rid of the loop over the columns.

Comment: @RemcoNiggebrugge could you add examples of the desired output for a given input?

Comment: Of course. The above matrix will give a result to big to put here, so a small example (I'll add it as answer, as I cannot add rich text format here)

Comment: Have a look at this very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29081378

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there is some inbuilt mechanism for your problem solution or not. But I have something which may helpful to you.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random_integers(0,6,(300,300))
b = np.random.random_integers(0,6,(300,300))

for i in xrange(300):
    a = np.roll(a, 1, axis=a)
    ###Do whatever you want to do with a and b
```

here all combination of matrix a will be generated so you can use it as per your use.

And you don't want to use loops may be because of time efficiency. but this will work faster because of numpy improved library

*I'm writing the answer on StackOverflow for the first time. So, if you find it's wrong then sorry!*

refrance: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html